# How do I sign out of Rockstar Social Club from within GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I got GTA V earlier this year, and a friend of mine was playing. He set up a random Rockstar Social Club account and now I would like to start a crew with another friend, but I can't set it up with the account that isn't mine. I have made my own account, but I don't know how to make it so my PSN account and that RSC account aren't linked.

Comment: You have to go into the RSC and disconnect it.  This cannot be done from within the game.